# How can I download slices of tick data using xbbg?

Tags: python, bloomberg

I've seen the previous question regarding downloading tick data using xbbg but that downloads the tick data from the previous day's 6pm open to present. I'm interested in pulling the data for specified minute intervals, for example 9:30AM-9:35AM. This is easily done in Excel using BDH but not in Python. Anyone have an idea? Thanks.

Comment: Just specify the start and end date?

Comment: @assylias Here's the logic in excel: =@BDH("ESU1 Index", "BID", "YYYY-MM-DD H:M:S" , "YYYY-MM-DD H:M:S", ...). Even if I specify the date and time (down to the microsecond), blp.bdh only returns the last bid/ask. Using blp.bdtick and specifying start date+time and end date+time also does not return the data. In addition, it returns trade data whereas I'm looking for bid/ask size.

Answer (score 0):

The xbbg documentation is somewhat sparse, however you can look into the code for `bdtick()`. In there you can see that it is possible to specify a time range:

```
from xbbg import blp
from datetime import datetime

df = blp.bdtick('ESZ1 Index',datetime(2021,8,17),types=['BID','ASK'],time_range=('09:00','09:05'),ref='CME')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                          ESZ1 Index                     
                                 typ    value volume exch
2021-08-17 09:00:00-04:00        BID  4443.50      2    M
2021-08-17 09:00:00-04:00        ASK  4444.75      1    M
2021-08-17 09:00:00-04:00        BID  4443.75      1    M
2021-08-17 09:00:00-04:00        ASK  4444.75      2    M
2021-08-17 09:00:00-04:00        ASK  4444.75      1    M
...                              ...      ...    ...  ...
2021-08-17 09:04:55-04:00        ASK  4444.50      6    M
2021-08-17 09:04:55-04:00        BID  4443.75      2    M
2021-08-17 09:04:56-04:00        BID  4443.75      1    M
2021-08-17 09:04:59-04:00        BID  4443.50      1    M
2021-08-17 09:04:59-04:00        BID  4443.75      1    M

[1188 rows x 4 columns]
```

The code uses the exchange reference 'CME' to determine the timezone, as it needs to convert the time range to UTC before sending to Bloomberg. For some tickers, xbbg is able to determine the exchange automatically. The config files are in the `...\Lib\site-packages\xbbg\markets` folder.